# Hovered item width expands so that it can fit all the content inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a drop down navigation bar and i have a problem. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7x5bs60g/)

What I want to achieve is that when the user mouses over a menu item and that item has children items, the navigation container height increases to fit all the content inside it. I managed to achieve that, but the problem is that the hovered item width expands so that it can fit all the content inside. How can I prevent that?

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="menu-container">
<ul class="main-menu clearfix">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Shop</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="dropdown float-child-to-right"><a href="">Filter by</a>
                <ul class="menu float-to-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Products</a>
                        <ul class="menu block-element">
                            <li><a href="">Guestbooks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Notebooks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown block-element"><a href="">Collections</a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="">Handle it</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tuff Love</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
 }

 ul {
    list-style: none;
 }
.container {
    border-bottom: #dedede 1px solid;
}
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
  clear: both;
}

 .main-menu li {

     float: left;
     min-width: 100px;

 }

.block-element li {
     float: none;
     display: block;
}

.float-to-right {
    float: right;
}

.main-menu li ul {
     /*display: none;*/
}

 .main-menu > ul {
     position: relative;
 }
```

and JS:

```
(function($){ 

        $.fn.recurse = function (_this,  _parent_dropdowns ) {


            _parent_dropdowns.each(function () {

                $(this).mouseover(function ( event ) {                  

                    var _uls = $(this).children('ul.menu');

                    _uls.each( function () {

                        //has float-to-right class
                        if ($(this).hasClass('float-to-right')) {

                        }

                    });

                    $(this).children('ul.menu').css({ display: 'block' });

                });

                $(this).mouseleave( function ( event ) {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    _this.children('li').find('ul.menu').each( function () {
                        $(this).css({ display: 'none' });
                    });


                });



                _this.recurse(_this, _parent_dropdowns.find('li.dropdowns'))
            });

        }

        $.fn.menufy = function () {

            return this.each(function () {

                var _parent_menu = $(this);

                var _parent_dropdowns = _parent_menu.find('li.dropdown');

                _parent_menu.recurse(_parent_menu, _parent_dropdowns);


            });

        }

    })(jQuery);

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.main-menu').menufy();
    });
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Is this the effect you are looking for? - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7x5bs60g/2/)

Comment: @UndoingTech no. I want the level 1 ul to be inline, the second level to be vertically displayed, and the third level to float to the right side of the parent item hovered. look at my fiddle, the problem is making the width of the "Shop" dont change so that the "contacts" item to doesnt move to the right. Also the container must adapt its height to fit its content. look at the bottom border in my fiddle. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7x5bs60g/3/) uses absolute positioning to keep the "Contacts" in the same place, but the bottom border is not displayed.  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Like that

```js
  (function($){ 

   $.fn.recurse = function (_this,  _parent_dropdowns ) {
    
   
    _parent_dropdowns.each(function () {

     $(this).mouseover(function ( event ) {     
      
      var _uls = $(this).children('ul.menu');

      _uls.each( function () {

       //has float-to-right class
       if ($(this).hasClass('float-to-right')) {
 
       }

      });
   
      $(this).children('ul.menu').css({ display: 'block' });
      
     });

     $(this).mouseleave( function ( event ) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      _this.children('li').find('ul.menu').each( function () {
       $(this).css({ display: 'none' });
      });
       

     });
     _this.recurse(_this, _parent_dropdowns.find('li.dropdowns'));
          
    });
    
   }
   
   $.fn.menufy = function () {

    return this.each(function () {

     var _parent_menu = $(this);

     var _parent_dropdowns = _parent_menu.find('li.dropdown');

     _parent_menu.recurse(_parent_menu, _parent_dropdowns);

     
    });

   }

  })(jQuery);

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('.main-menu').menufy();
  });
```

```css
 * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 ul {
  list-style: none;
 }
.container {
 border-bottom: #dedede 1px solid;
}
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}

.main-menu li {

 float: left;
 min-width: 100px;

}

.block-element li {
 float: none;
 display: block;
}

.float-to-right {
 float: right;
}

.main-menu li ul {
 display: none;
}

.main-menu > ul {
 position: relative;
}
.shop{width:50%;float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="menu-container">
 <ul class="main-menu clearfix">
  <li class="dropdown shop"><a href="">Shop</a>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown shop"><a href="">Filter by</a>
     <ul class="menu float-to-right">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Products</a>
       <ul class="menu block-element">
        <li><a href="">Guestbooks</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Notebooks</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown block-element"><a href="">Collections</a>
       <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Handle it</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tuff Love</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.